# How to make my SvelteKit API work in production (Github Pages)?

Tags: github-pages, svelte, sveltekit

### Background

I have my project deployed to Github Pages here: https://zeddrix.github.io/jw-guitar-tabs, so I have this in my **svelte.config.js** file:

```
kit: {
    ...
    paths: {
        base: '/jw-guitar-tabs'
    },
    appDir: 'internal',
    ...
}
```

I have this in my **__layout.svelte**:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { base } from '$app/paths';
    ...
    const fetchFromDBAndStore = async (category: SongCategoriesType) => {
        const res = await fetch(`${base}/api/categories/original-songs`);
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);

    ...other code...
    };

    ...I have my code here that uses this data...
</script>

<Layout><slot /></Layout>
```

**Side note:** I put it in this file so that this runs on any page, but I have a code to make sure that this doesn't run if I already have the data. *This is not the issue.*

This calls on the file: **src/routes/api/categories/original-songs.ts**:

```
import fetchSongsDB from '$utils/fetchSongsDB';

export const get = async () => fetchSongsDB('originals');
```

And this `fetchSongsDB` function fetches the songs from my database.

Everything is working fine in **development mode** when I run `npm run dev` and even in **preview mode** when I run `npm run preview` *after build*, of course, in `localhost:3000/jw-guitar-tabs`.

[image]

### Issue

However, on the static github page at https://zeddrix.github.io/jw-guitar-tabs, I get this:

[image]

[image]

It serves the 404 Github Page as the response. I guess it's because it can't find the **src/routes/api/categories/original-songs.ts** file. But of course Github will not find this file because the deployed folder to gh-pages is the build folder so I don't have this original ***file*** route anymore.

[image]

How would I solve this?

Comment: I am: `"@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^1.0.0-next.26"`. That's why I was able to deploy my project to github. Is the issue related with this?

Comment: Unsure, I asked because I was thinking it would cause issues if it were absent — you're right though, without it you wouldn't have made it onto Github Pages in the first place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that GitHub Pages only can serves static file, so you can't run any server-side code (in this case, your API endpoint). If you need to run a Node.js app (so that you can execute server-side code), you need something like a VPS provided by DigitalOcean, Linode, or other provider, or you can use free alternative like [Deta.sh](https://www.deta.sh/) to host your Node.js app as a serverless app.

Comment: You can try deploying the same site on Vercel or Cloudflare Pages (they are both free up to a certain point).

Most probably the issue is the same as @Owl described: Github Pages cannot run server functions.

Or you are trying to access the database that is not reachable from the deployed backend.

Comment: @Owl—[this site](https://svelteland.github.io/svelte-kit-blog-demo/create-your-blog) is deployed to GitHub Pages and calls a SvelteKit endpoint. I don't know whether he can connect to MongoDB after hitting the endpoint, but I feel at least he should not be getting a 404.

Comment: @kenset it calls a `.json` "endpoint", which is a static file just like HTML (https://svelteland.github.io/svelte-kit-blog-demo/create-your-blog.json), which is stored [here](https://github.com/svelteland/svelte-kit-blog-demo/tree/main/src/posts)

Comment: The static files you reference would correspond to @Zedd's Mongo query — but @Zedd should at least be able to hit the endpoint just as svelteland.github.io can hit the `[slug].json.js` endpoint.

Comment: Seems like the `[slug].json.js` is only used for dev server or when building. I just tested on one of my Svelte Kit app, using adapter static strips out all endpoint routes (most likely because the adapter is only used to generate static file). If you do a network inspection on svelteland, it doesn't seem to hit `[slug].json.js`, rather than accessing a static `.json` file. I tried to clone and build the `svelte-kit-blog-demo` app, and it seems to bundle `create-your-blog.json`, `decoration.json`, `deploy-to-github.json` on the root build directory rather than using "endpoint" to fetch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Rename `original-songs.ts` to `original-songs.json.ts`
2. Change the

```
fetch(`${base}/api/categories/original-songs`);
```

to

```
fetch(`${base}/api/categories/original-songs.json`);
```

That allows the adapter-static to generate the json files *at build time*.
(These are static files, to see changes made in mongodb will require a rebuild & redeploy to GitHub pages)

3. Sometimes the static adapter doesn't autodetect the endpoint.
   You can help the adapter by specifying the url in svelte.config.js

```json
  kit: {
    prerender: {
      entries: [
        "*",
        "/api/categories/original-songs.json",
```

4. Bonus tip: The `/favorites` url redirects to `/favorites/` when refreshing the page, add `trailingSlash: "never",` to kit to generate `favorites.html` instead of `favorites/index.html` and keep the `/favorites` url on refresh.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! So this means that everytime I modified the data in my db, I'll need to always build and deploy, since it's prerendered, right?

Comment: What about directly getting the data from the db, will that be possible in a static website, to avoid the hustle of building & deploying again and again? And even if that were possible, I still need to wait for the standalone endpoints feature (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#standalone-endpoints) to get this done, coz there's no other way to get this done, am I right?

Comment: That the limitation of static hosting. A method would be to create a CSR/SPA and use a database providers that has an api that is accessible from the client (like Firebase's "Cloud Firestore" for example). but not sure if thats good fit for a sveltekit site.